# How to create a stacked donut chart in Angular 5

Tags: chart.js, angular5, donut-chart

How to create a stacked donut chart in angular5?

I am not familiar in Angular5

Answer (score 0):

[PrimeNG's Doughnut](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/doughnut) might be work a look.